# Can't install pip for python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x

I added `C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Scripts` to the `PATH` environment variable, downloaded `get-pip.py` and ran it. However, when I execute `pip` in the `cmd`, nothing shows up.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: What if you type `pip3`?

Comment: still, nothing shows up.

Comment: When you say *nothing*, do you mean *literally nothing*? I.e. it just ignores your input and shows a new prompt?

Comment: yes,it just shows a new prompt.

Comment: Clarified and formatted the question.

Comment: Can you find out where the `pip` command is you're calling (on *nix, this would be `which pip`; I don't know a Windows equivalent)? If you find the command, you can have a look at it: it should be a Python script.

Comment: Also, try importing pip into python in the interpreter: `>>> import pip; pip.__file__`, and then have a look inside the package location given by `__file__`.